# #REF! error Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C33

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have several cells with #REF! but most do not.  I cannot figure out why those few keep getting the #REF!   error.  Error states:  Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C33
My formula is:  `=iferror(query('Proposal Legend'!$A$2:$B$1101,"select A where B = '"&B32&"'",0),"")`

Comment: No!  First time user and not very proficient in formulas.  I will try and change the tags

Comment: There is no reason that should be a problem if you in fact don't have any content in cell C33. Perhaps a link to an example sheet or images would help. Is this formula posted in Column C?

Comment: The content in C33 is the formula for that cell:  =iferror(query('Proposal Legend'!$A$2:$B$1101,"select A where B = '"&B33&"'",0),"")

Comment: That is suggesting you have more content below cell C33 that is intersecting the array.

Comment: I dragged the formula down the row from the lower right corner to populate the cells.  After 30 or so cells, the errors stop.

Comment: The query function returns an array. Therefore you only need to paste the formula in a single cell and it will auto-populate the information down and to the right (if desired). Just be sure all the content below C33 is cleared of any and all information.

Comment: Not sure about your case, but in my case I had a formula like
[`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(A2:A/B2:B))`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57733).
I replaced it with the simpler `=IFERROR(A2:A/B2:B)` (thus removing `ARRAYFORMULA`), and the `#REF!` error went away.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have content below cell C33 that is interfering with the returned results of your QUERY function. See image below:
[image]

We are querying all the items in Column A that have a YES value in column B. Similar to your formula.

However, if I enter a value in cell D3 I get an error due to the fact that my above formula wants to return 3 results, but in the 3rd cell of results I already have information.

[image]